# PyInstaller not working on simple HelloWorld Program

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

So I am running on 64-bit Windows 7, and I set up Pyinstaller with Pip and PyWin32. I have python 2.7.

I made a simple hello world Program with this code

```
print "hello world!"
```

I put the file in the same directory as PyInstaller, and ran this code in the command prompt

```
pyinstaller.py helloWorld.py
```

Yet, when I try that, I get this error message:

```
Error loading Python DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\PYINST~1.1\build\HELLOW~1\python27.dll (error code 126)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Run with the -F flag to produce the standalone exe:

```
pyinstaller -F helloworld.py
```

It will output to dist/helloworld.exe

NOTE this is a different location to when -F is not used, be sure to run the right exe afterwards.

Comment: It's worth noting that it now appears to output to `dist/{filename}`, rather then `build/{filename}`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect the new location

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @tul! My version of pyinstaller put it to ***dist***\helloworld.exe though!

If you start it from *C:\Python27\Scripts...* that'll be *C:\Python27\Scripts\dist...* as well!

But whereever you have it, I recommend putting a **batch file** next to your .py to be able recompile any time with just a click:

I set it up so there is nothing but the .exe at the .py location and the temporary stuff goes to the temp dir:

```
@echo off
:: get name from filename without path and ext
set name=%~n0
echo ========= %name% =========

:: cut away the suffix "_build"
set name=%name:~0,-6%
set pypath=C:\Python27\Scripts
set buildpath=%temp%

if not exist %name%.py (
    echo ERROR: "%name%.py" does not exist here!
    pause
    exit /b
)

%pypath%\pyinstaller.exe --onefile -y %~dp0%name%.py --distpath=%~dp0 --workpath=%buildpath% --specpath=%buildpath%
```

I name it like the .py file plus "_build" and cut away the suffix in the batch script again.
Voilà.