# error loading python27.dll (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I Converted my python programme to an exe using pyinstaller.

It works fine on the computer i converted it on, But all other computers give the following error:

```
Error loading python DLL: c:\Users\win8\Downloads\Up2048\Up2048mew\python27.dll <error code 14001>
```

i compiled the exe with no modifying commands:\

I have attempted to add the latest version of VC++ but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller not working on simple HelloWorld Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225132/pyinstaller-not-working-on-simple-helloworld-program)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved upgrading the pip.

Run the command pip install --upgrade pyinstaller and be happy. :)