# Error loading Python dll/ LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am new at programming. I wrote a small program in python and converted it to .exe file with `pyinstaller`. Now when i try to open the .exe file a black screen appears and closes immediately. I was able to get a screenshot:

[image]

I saw a solution like adding `input()` at the end of the code but it didn't work either. My code:

```
import random

print("Hello, what is your name?")
name = str(input())
print("Well, " + name + ", I think of a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess this number in 10 chances?")
number = random.randint(1, 1001)

for guessTaken in range(1, 11):
  print("Take a guess")
  guess = int(input())
  if guess > number:
    print("The number you think is too high")
  elif guess < number:
    print("The number you think is too low")
  else:
    break

if guess == number:
  print("OK, " + name + ", you guessed the number in " + str(guessTaken) + " guesses")
else:
  print("Unfortunatelly, you couldn't find the number. The number is " + str(number))
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This worked for me:

> Had the same issue but then realized that I was inadvertently trying to execute the file in the `build` folder instead of the `dist` folder.
>
> Looks like you might be making the same mistake from your traceback so see if using the executable in `dist` doesn't fix it for you

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119819/4607733)

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well. Why isn't this in the manual? Based on the number of questions about it, seems like it would save a lot of people's time if it was.

Comment: So, I found it in the Usage. But I still think it should be spelled out more clearly in the written guide.

Comment: Ok so it's also in the "Using Pyinstaller" section.

Comment: :-) I am a stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's because you have created the exe file that depends on the entire folder. That's why it is working only in the dist folder.

Simple Solution:

Create the exe file using pyinstaller with onefile option.
It will only creates the exe file in the dist folder and can execute anywhere we want.

use the bellow command in cmd.

> > pyinstaller --onefile file_name.py

Answer (score 4):

The problem seen in the screenshot is that the Python Library cannot be found. So some configuration in your pyinstaller is wrong. Are you sure that python36.dll is in that folder? Check where your python36.dll is located (normally in the same folder where your python installation is located and your python.exe can be found). Maybe you need to add this path to your Windows Path Configuration?

Please check the following two answers to see if your pyinstaller is configured correctly:

[PyInstaller not working on simple HelloWorld Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225132/pyinstaller-not-working-on-simple-helloworld-program)

[Error loading python27.dll error for pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194463/error-loading-python27-dll-error-for-pyinstaller)

The situation should be similar for you with Python 3.6

Comment: Which means by the way that your program cannot be run at all. You can still run your python file directly to see if that works by opening a command line and running it with something along the lines `python myfile.py` if your script is called `myfile.py`

Comment: I checked the folder, there is python36.dll. I added path and reconverted the program. Still same. It worked with command line

Comment: I added two links to similar problems, it seems your pyinstaller needs more configuration.