# Loading symbols from a DLL loaded with a non-standard path that forward to another DLL

Tags: c, windows, dll, getprocaddress

I'm trying to dynamically load a DLL (python3.dll) which isn't on the normal search path. I can load it with an altered search path, but when I do `GetProcAddress`, it's failing (because the function I'm loading forwards to another DLL, python37.dll).

I think what I need to do is get `GetProcAddress` to follow the same search logic as in my original DLL load, but I don't know how to so that without altering the system `PATH` (which has all sorts of other potential issues, as my code goes on to let the user run their own code, which needs the *original* path).

Is there a clean solution for this?

Here's the code I tried:

```
HMODULE py_dll = LoadLibraryW(L"python3.dll");
if (!py_dll) {
    py_dll = LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\Work\\Projects\\pylaunch\\py3embed\\python3.dll", NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
}

if (!py_dll) {
    printf("Cannot load Python DLL\n");
    err();
    return 1;
}
char buf[1000];
GetModuleFileName(py_dll, buf, 1000);
printf("DLL is %s\n", buf);
Py_Main_t Py_Main = (Py_Main_t)GetProcAddress(py_dll, "Py_Main");
if (!Py_Main) {
    printf("Cannot load Py_Main\n");
    err();
    return 1;
}
```

Adding `SetDllDirectory()` didn't seem to help, but I just dumped a call to it into the code, as I wasn't 100% clear on how it worked, so it's possible I did something wrong.

For reference, the definition of the Py_Main symbol is

```
 747  2EA          Py_Main (forwarded to python37.Py_Main)
```

Comment: Never worked with *pylaunch*, but I have a feeling that *python3.dll* is a shim, that references the real *Python3* one. Why not loading the referenced *.dll* directly? Also, could you post *SetDllDirectory* code? Is there any case when *python3.dll* points to *python35.dll* (wherever this is located)?

Comment: Your scenario makes me wonder if your python installation went well.  Is it a standard installation?  Here are _[some conversations down that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289279/error-loading-python-dll-loadlibrary-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)_ if you think that might be an issue. (dealing with the _other_ python, but paths are still paths in any language.)

Comment: @CristiFati `python3.dll` is part of the Python distribution, it forwards all references to `python37.dll`. It's needed so that your code can load a (minor) version independent DLL and work with any Python version. See PEP 384 for the details. The SetDllDirectory code is nothing more than `SetDllDirectoryW(L"C:\\Work\\Projects\\pylaunch\\py3embed");` (before `LoadLibrary`).

Comment: @ryyker The installation is a copy of the standard embedded Python distribution. It's sound (it works for other embedded apps).

Comment: Which of the Python37 installers is the one you used, 32bit or 64bit?  I am wondering if the `system` versus `SysWoW64` locations are a factor in default search behavior of `LoadLibrary_x_` functions.

Comment: @ryyker `python-3.7.0-embed-amd64.zip` on a 64-bit machine. If I move the exe to the `py3embed` directory (so the `LoadLibrary` call with no path succeeds) it works fine. It's only when I need to load from a relative path that it fails. The `SysWow` location is irrelevant (as far as I know) because it's not an installed Python distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is a problem with Windows 7. The discussion [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue29399) gives more details.

Basically, `GetProcAddress` doesn't appear to respect changes to the search path using `SetDllDirectory` when loading additional DLLs to resolve forwarded symbols. If the DLL containing the forwarding symbol has a dependency on the target DLL, it *does* work, but `python3.dll` doesn't have such a dependency.

From a report in the Python issue linked above, it appears that this behaviour has been fixed in Windows 10, so you need to be on Windows 7 to see the problem.

The solution seems to be to update Windows, or avoid using `GetProcAddress` with forwarded functions (unless the forwarder has a dependency on the target).